Suggestions for My Interactive Visualization Web Tool for Robotic Learning
I am a Digital IC designer in Taiwan. Recently, I started studying Robotics by myself, but I've been frustrated by the math involved, including Euler angles, Quaternions, and DH models. They were just introduced in Chapter 1. I think the mathematics are too difficult for the average person to understand, and I wish there were a visualization website that could demonstrate the concepts of each transformation method or robotic modeling approach.
Consequently, I developed VisRo, a website focused on visualizing robotic learning. I wrote version 0.1.0 of the website this weekend. Currently, it features visualizations of:

Translation and Rotation
Euler Angles
Quaternions
Homogeneous Translation
Classic DH Parameters
Modified DH Parameters

I think the visualization of DH parameters now is really awesome. Please give it a try!
You can not only tune the parameters and see the results immediately, but there is also step-by-step animation from the initial stage to the final stage.
I plan to add more visualization views, including inverse kinematics and dynamics, to help students learn robotics more efficiently. However, I'm not sure if what I've done is the best solution for learning robotics. I need your advice on what I can do on the website to help people learn robotics faster.
Feel free to check out the website and give me advice. Thanks very much for your advice.
VisRo: https://vis-ro.web.app/
Here are some snapshot of my website:




Very cool! Maybe make the input fields a little bigger. It would also be great to have sliders instead of needing to adjust the numbers directly.

That said, this is not really a question and doesn't have a right answer so this doesn't really belong here. Perhaps you want to post this on ROS Discourse instead? https://discourse.ros.org

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
